# Neural network time series normalization

Tags: artificial-intelligence, time-series, pattern-recognition, pybrain, lstm

I am using LSTM as the hidden layer function in a time series prediction network. Is input normalization necessary? If it is, is data = data / sum(data) the correct normalization? 
Should the output also be normalized with the inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is input normalization necessary?**

No, but it might make your network converge faster. Use this calculation to scale your values to [0,1]:

[image: normalization].

**Should the output also be normalized with the inputs?**

No, I can't think of a reason why you would ever want to do that.

Comment: what would you do for scaling, if your time-series contain extreme values?